# Parse data from Microsoft SQL Server database to android application

Tags: android, sql, xml, database, parsing

My application requirement is: i have to parse data from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 to android application and as well as have to send data from android Application to server.
How to parse data from and MS SQL Server database to android app? I have done testing to send data from android app to Server.
which methods can I use? If not, is there any alternative ways to parse?

Can anyone help me? Thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Create a REST or SOAP Service with MS SQL Server as Backend. Connect to this service from your application to request or upload data. Most of those services accept and return XML data. JSON   is also widely used.

[Work with XML Data in Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)

Comment: i dont know about JSON. I have never used JSON. i have worked for PHP Server,where i wrote php script + XML to parse data.. but the problem is there i how to parse data using c# language(c# script) to android app? any guidence?

Comment: What do you want with c#? If you write an Android app you should be using Java?! See my updated answer for a link to work with xml data and Android